# ng-select remove the element in programmatic way in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select, angular-ngselect

I am trying to remove the selected element from the ng-select using the program. As we can delete it using click cross button but we want to delete programmatic way in Angular 6. Please help me to find a perfect solution.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your stackblitz

Comment: what component are you using for select box?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pv5rcw   

@Aarsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want only this line :

```
this.selectedCityIds = this.selectedCityIds.filter(s => s != id);
```

Which is you can use it in your function in this way;

```
deleteSingle (id: string) {
  this.selectedCityIds = this.selectedCityIds.filter(s => s != id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-select` is 2-way bound with `selectedCityIds`, this is what the `[(ngModel)]` notation does. Meaning, changing one (either the GUI ng-select or the class property `selectedCityIds`) changes the other. Here is a proposed solution:

I created a text input which lets users type the name of a city.

```html
<label>Type name of city to delete</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cityToDelete" style="margin-left: 10px" />
```

Then, your `deleteSingle` method is completed like this:

```js
// This is the property bound to the text input
cityToDelete: string = "";
deleteSingle () {
  // This will be the city to delete
  const city = this.cities2.find(c => c.name === this.cityToDelete);
  // If city with this name is found in list, then it's removed
  if(city != null) {
    console.log(city);
    this.selectedCityIds = this.selectedCityIds.filter(id => id !== city.id);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6lexy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Try it out:

1. Add "Vilnius" and "Kaunas" to your `ng-select`.
2. Type one of the above names in the text input.
3. Click "Delete City By name"

You will see the city name you typed will be removed from the GUI. The code searched your `ng-select` data source, which is `cities2` in your example. If a city with the name the user types is not found in `cities2`, no action is taken.